# Android. How i can shake emulator in test with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-emulator, adb, android-espresso

I try exec command `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh -c 'adb emu sensor set acceleration 100:100:100; sleep 1; adb emu sensor set acceleration 0:0:0'")`
But is not work
Also a try

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("emu sensor set acceleration 100:100:100")
Thread.sleep(1_000)
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("emu sensor set acceleration 0:0:0")
```

And get error denied permission for command emu

Comment: I would try to use the "sensor replay" feature. https://stackoverflow.com/q/70973129/150978